# Error: Timeout of 2000ms exceeded. For async tests and hooks, ensure "done()" - How to avoid this error?

Tags: node.js, sinon, nock, sinon-chai

**Code:**

```
var processFooBar = function (message, callback) {

  doFooAndBar(message, callback);

};
module.exports.processFooBar = processFooBar;


var doFooAndBar = function (data, callback) {
    async.parallel(
        [
            function (callback) {
                foo(data, function (err, response) {
                    callback(err, response);
                });
            },
            function (callback) {
                bar(data, function (err, response){
                    callback(err, response);
                });
            }
        ],
        function (err, results) {
            callback(err, results);
        }
    );
};
module.exports.doFooBar = doFooBar;
```

**Unit Test**

```
describe('Process data', function () {
    var fooStub;

    beforeEach(function (done) {
        done();
    });

    afterEach(function (done) {
        fooStub.restore();
        done();
    });

    it('can process data', function (done) {
        fooStub = sinon.stub(fileName, 'foo').yields(null, null);
        barNockCall();
        app.processFooBar(message,
            function (err, response) {
                nock.isDone().should.be.true;
                nock.cleanAll();
                done();
            }
        }
    });
```

I am getting the following error:

```
can process data:
  Error: Timeout of 2000ms exceeded. For async tests and hooks, ensure "done()" is called; if returning a Promise, ensure it resolves. 
(/Path/To/Test.js)
```

If I remove foo() in async.parallel, then I don't get the error. Also, I guess the first sinon.stub that is fooStubis not getting called.

Comment: This code is very far from [mcve] especially in terms of completeness.

Comment: Make it reproducible using RunKit. I maintain Sinon and often use this to reproduce cases. It's like coding Node in the browser. Example: https://runkit.com/fatso83/5bbfafa21ebc47001398e7de

Answer (score 0):

You need to increase the test framework's timeout. It might have default timeout of 2000ms and will throw error if the request takes more than 2 sec.

```
beforeEach(function (done) {
 this.timeout(10000)
 done();
});
```

Overriding the default timeout might work in your case.